# Repair system gem installation in OSX

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I fool-hardily removed my system installation of gem. I was trying to get rbenv to work and was having some problems so I thought I could easily re-install all my Ruby stuff and start from scratch. This however is clearly not the case.

Any ideas short of breaking out the system disk would be appreciated.